# Trying to us str.contains and boolean mask but for only two instances of single value in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, boolean, pandas-groupby

What I am trying to do is keep all rows with the same unique `ID` IF any of those rows contain only two instances of “ – “ in the Yurt column.

I'm thinking of using a `str.contains` and a boolean mask by doing the following:

```
df[df['ID'].isin(df.loc[df.Yurt.str.contains('-'), 'ID'].unique())]
```

...but unsure of how I'd only keep rows with only two instances with no value.

Example df:

```
ID      %       Yurt
abc123  0.833   Bodega
abc123  0.87    -
abc123  0.867   -
abc123  0.812   -
lmn789  0.837   Mickey's
lmn789  0.856   Chopped Cheese
lmn789  0.813   -
lmn789  0.812   -
xyz456  0.111   -
xyz456  0.222   -
xyz456  0.333   -
xyz456  0.444   -
```

Result df:

```
ID      %       Yurt
lmn789  0.837   Mickey's
lmn789  0.856   Chopped Cheese
lmn789  0.813   -
lmn789  0.812   -
```

Answer (score 5):

Perform a `groupby` on the 'ID' column and use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
df = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda grp: grp['Yurt'].eq('-').sum() == 2)
```

Output:

```
       ID      %            Yurt
4  lmn789  0.837        Mickey's
5  lmn789  0.856  Chopped Cheese
6  lmn789  0.813               -
7  lmn789  0.812               -
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GroupBy.size` to calculate in-scope values. Then filter your original dataframe.

```
nulls = df[df['Yurt'] == '-'].groupby('ID').size()

df = df[df['ID'].isin(nulls[nulls == 2].index)]

print(df)

       ID      %           Yurt
4  lmn789  0.837       Mickey's
5  lmn789  0.856  ChoppedCheese
6  lmn789  0.813              -
7  lmn789  0.812              -
```

You may find this more efficient than a custom `lambda` function:

```
def jpp(df):
    nulls = df[df['Yurt'] == '-'].groupby('ID').size()
    return df[df['ID'].isin(nulls[nulls == 2].index)]

def root(df):
    return df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda grp: grp['Yurt'].eq('-').sum() == 2)

%timeit jpp(df)   # 2.99 ms per loop
%timeit root(df)  # 4.93 ms per loop
```